# Cypher query to find nodes, then find counts of those nodes that have a particular relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I'm using neo4j to represent employers and their health benefit offerings. ie :

`(client)-[OFFERED_PLAN]->(planOffering)-[HAS_PLAN_DETAIL {value:number}]->(benefitPlanType)`

I'm trying to query this graph to get the top 50 clients in CA, then to get the number of those 50 clients that offer a medical plan (value = 1) and how many offered dental (value = 5). I've tried many variations of the below query, but I think this is the closest. The output of this will currently return the same number for all three variables, 25, which is the number of these clients offering dental.

```
MATCH (client:Client)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(:State {stateCode:'CA'})
LIMIT 50
with client as mc, client as dc, client
MATCH (mc)-[:OFFERED_PLAN]->(mp:PlanOffering)-[mbpt:HAS_PLAN_DETAIL]->(:BenefitPlanType),
      (dc)-[:OFFERED_PLAN]->(:PlanOffering)-[dbpt:HAS_PLAN_DETAIL]->(:BenefitPlanType)
WHERE mbpt.value = 1 and dbpt.value = 5
with  count(distinct(client.clientID)) as clientCount,  
      count(distinct(mc.clientID)) as numberMedicalClients,  
      count(distinct(dc.clientID)) as numberDentalClients
return *
```

Comment: Did you actually mean "any 50" clients instead of "top 50"? Your query (once the syntax errors are fixed) is not doing anything to filter the `client` nodes.

Answer (score 4):

Can't test this query but if you simply aggregate the clients by the plan value, then you'd get the number of clients on each plan, without having to re-match them

```
MATCH (client:Client)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(:State {stateCode:'CA'})
WITH client LIMIT 50
MATCH (client)-[:OFFERED_PLAN]->(mp:PlanOffering)-[mbpt:HAS_PLAN_DETAIL]->(:BenefitPlanType)
WHERE mbpt.value IN [1,5]
RETURN mbpt.value, count(*)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking a look into this! I'll give this a shot, however at first glance I think that and any client that offers more than one of those benefitPlanTypes will be counted multiple times

Comment: If a client offers say, two benefit plans, one of value 1 and one of 5, then this query should produce 2 rows- one for value 1 and one for value 5. But after reading your comment, maybe that is not the intent? Anyway, happy to help more especially if there's a sample graph somewhere to try this on

Comment: That scenario would be fine and your query works in that regard. However there is the scenario where a client could offer multiple plans with a bpt value of 1, and multiple of 5. For example, clientA could offer 10 plans with bpt = 1, and then 3 plans with bpt = 5, and in this query the results would have a row for bpt 1 and 5, but the count would 10 and 3, which is the count of plans and not the count of clients that offered each bpt, 1 and 1.

Comment: Ah I see. Can you try MATCH (client:Client)-[:LOCATED_IN]->(:State {stateCode:'CA'})
WITH client LIMIT 50
MATCH (client)-[:OFFERED_PLAN]->(mp:PlanOffering)-[mbpt:HAS_PLAN_DETAIL]->(:BenefitPlanType)
WHERE mbpt.value IN [1,5]
RETURN mbpt.value, count(distinct client)

or something like this